# one table data insert into different table with sum and group by in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to show total purchase followed by date from  purchase table to insert into total_purchase table as in date and buy as well as view

```
my purchase table structure as below:

 id|companyName |purchase|date
  1|housedotcom |1300    |2016-1-1
  2|homedotcom  |1234    |2016-1-1
  3|gardendotco |1000    |2016-1-2
  4|landotcom   |999     |2016-1-2
  5|garagedotcom|5400    |2016-1-2
  6|homedotcom  |2600    |2016-1-2
  7|housedotcom |1900    |2016-1-2

  my total_purchase table as below

   id|date    |buy
    1|2016-1-1|2534
    2|2016-2-2|20890
```

I tried this into sql

```
INSERT INTO 'total_purchase'(date,buy) SELECT date, sum(purchase)
*FROM 'purchase' GROUP BY date;
```

And it showed in mysql result as I expected but when I tried insert new data into purchase table as same companyName with different date in mysql it says duplicate as well as in php coding sql it did not worked and showed this error

> Error Processing RequestSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM purchaseGROUP BY date'

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove * from your query to be:

```
INSERT INTO total_purchase (date,buy) SELECT date, sum(purchase)
FROM purchase GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: In mysql it works, however when I try to  insert new data into purchase it say duplicated in mysql. And can you suggested me how  inserting new data to add total purchase table from purchase by php

Comment: you must not repeat your primary key data. so you can make id as primary key and make it auto incremental

Answer (score 0):

For inserting value should be entered by just column by column.In Select you use * that return row more than one remove '*'

```
INSERT INTO 'total_purchase'(date,buy) SELECT date, sum(purchase)
FROM 'purchase' GROUP BY date;
```